# Crossplatform hosts file location

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hosts

Is there any documented guarantee that `hosts` file will be in:

- `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows
- `/private/etc/hosts` on OS X
- and in `/etc/hosts` on Linux

?

Or there exists some API to retrieve hosts file location?

In other words, can I hard code these paths in crossplatform (Win/OSX/Linux) app?

**UPD** On Windows path to `hosts` file is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters\DataBasePath`, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750301.aspx

Comment: The linux paths appears to be correct. I have never seen an exception there. However that file might be ignored by configuration and it certainly is possible to specify another path at compile time. I cannot really imagine anyone doing that, but then again you never know...

Comment: `/etc` on OSX is just a symbolic link to `/private/etc` so they amount to the same thing.